# Prove that limit of function is equal to zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives, improper-integrals

We have a function $f(x)$ defined on $ [0, +\infty)$.

It is known that $|f'(x)|<2$.

Prove that if $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$ converges then $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=0$.

I don't really know how to use the fact about derivative, I would like to apply LHopital's rule in order to jump from integral to function and then to derivative, but it is not suitable here.

Comment: I think it's $x$ @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: can you see why this is the case?

Comment: [*This*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240140/limit-of-uniformly-continuous-functions-with-convergent-improper-integrals/2240166#2240166) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Show that $|f'(x)|<2$ implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous in  $[0, +\infty)$. Then take a look here: [$f$ uniformly continuous and $\int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges imply $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/f-uniformly-continuous-and-int-a-infty-fx-dx-converges-imply-lim-x)